# Simulating UP arrow keybd_event (not working?)

Tags: c++, keyboard-events

```
keybd_event(VK_UP, MapVirtualKey(VK_UP, 0), 0, 0); //pressed
Sleep(100);
keybd_event(VK_UP, MapVirtualKey(VK_UP, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //released
Sleep(300);
```

The following is not automatically pressing the UP arrow and releasing it like it should. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.*

Answer (score 3):

The [keybd_event function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is obsolete. It has been superseded by the [SendInput function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The following code might do what you want.

```
UINT SendUpArrow()
{
    INPUT input[2] = {0};
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk = VK_UP;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[1].ki.wVk = VK_UP;
    input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    UINT ret = ::SendInput(_countof(input), input, sizeof(INPUT));
    return ret;
}
```